# Change name of the video file using youtube-dl not working

Tags: video, youtube-dl

I am downloading a video file from a link using youtube-dl.
https://res.cloudinary.com/dqozdyzvu/video/upload/v1514809216/29836749002162.mp4

```
youtube-dl https://res.cloudinary.com/dqozdyzvu/video/upload/v1514809216/29836749002162.mp4
```

The name of the file that is getting saved is

```
29836749002162.29836749002162.mp4
```

I want to change the name of the file to video.mp4. I tried using this command

```
youtube-dl -o '%(video)s.%(mp4)s' https://res.cloudinary.com/dqozdyzvu/video/upload/v1514809216/29836749002162.mp4
```

But it saved as:

```
NA.NA
```

What changes could be made in the command to save the file exactly as **Video.mp4**?

Comment: Why not using `wget` for downloading direct links? `wget -ct0 -O video.mp4 http://link.com/video30303.mp4`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
youtube-dl -o video.mp4 https://res.cloudinary.com/dqozdyzvu/video/upload/v1514809216/29836749002162.mp4
```

This command saves the file exactly as video.mp4 in the current directory.

The `%` characters in `'%(video)s.%(mp4)s'` in your question are used to denote an output template which will be replaced by the actual value corresponding to the sequence name. Note that some of the sequences are not guaranteed to be present since they depend on the metadata obtained by a particular extractor. Such sequences will be replaced with `NA` which stands for **N**ot **A**vailable.